# How do get this to output the correct slope on the graph using javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

[y=mx+b graph equation sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKdY8.png)

In the given picture, it shows that the slope painted by the program is incorrect.
when the slider bar for the m coefficient is negative the slope still shows positive.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the for loop when painting each dot on the graph but I cant seem to figure it out. When I change the x to negative it shows only the negative slope. do I need an if statement and if so what should it say?

```
   private final int X_MIN = -10, Y_MIN = -10, X_MAX = 10, Y_MAX = 10;
   private final int REAL_WORLD_WIDTH = X_MAX - X_MIN;
   private final int REAL_WORLD_HEIGHT = Y_MAX - Y_MIN;
   private final double TICK_LENGTH = 0.2;

   private Equation equation;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up this panel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public EquationViewportPanel()
   {
      equation = new Equation();
      setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 4));
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets the equation.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   void setEquation(Equation newEquation)
   {
      equation = newEquation;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Converts world X coordinate to screen X coordinate.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private int convertX(double x)
   {
      double offset = x - X_MIN;
      double result = offset * getSize().width / REAL_WORLD_WIDTH;
      return (int) Math.round(result);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Converts world Y coordinate to screen Y coordinate.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private int convertY(double y)
   {
      double offset = Y_MAX - y;
      double result = offset * getSize().height / REAL_WORLD_HEIGHT;
      return (int) Math.round(result);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws a line in world coordinates on the screen.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private void drawScreenLine(Graphics page, double xMin, double yMin,
      double xMax, double yMax)
   {
      page.drawLine(convertX(xMin), convertY(yMin), convertX(xMax), convertY(yMax));
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws a point in world coordinates on the screen.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private void drawScreenPoint(Graphics page, double x, double y)
   {
      page.drawLine(convertX(x), convertY(y), convertX(x), convertY(y));
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws the graph axes and equation.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
   {
      page.setColor(Color.white);
      page.fillRect(0,0,getSize().width, getSize().height);

      // draw the x and y axis
      page.setColor(Color.red);
      drawScreenLine(page, X_MIN, 0, X_MAX, 0);
      drawScreenLine(page, 0, Y_MIN, 0, Y_MAX);

      // draw tick marks
      for (int x=X_MIN; x<X_MAX; x++)
         drawScreenLine(page, x, -TICK_LENGTH, x, TICK_LENGTH);
      for (int y=Y_MIN; y<Y_MAX; y++)
         drawScreenLine(page, -TICK_LENGTH, y, TICK_LENGTH, y);

      // draw the graph of the equation
      page.setColor(Color.black);
      double x = X_MIN;
      double y;
      double stepSize = (double)(X_MAX - X_MIN) / getSize().width;
      int screenX = getSize().width;
      for (int i = 0; i <= screenX; i++)
      {
         y = equation.computeValue(x);
         drawScreenPoint(page, x, y);

         x += stepSize;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The conversion of graph coordinates to screen coordinates seems correct (screen starts top left and goes down / right for increasing y/x respectively).

Comment: So as a simple test what happens if you draw a line using the equation from x=-X_MIN to x=X_MAX - does that do the right thing?  It seems like it ought to work because the line drawing stuff seems to be working cause of the x and y axis and ticks being draws - which just leaves the equation - which isn't shown....

Comment: The point of the simple test is - to check whether the equation is working correctly - if you don't get the value you expect from it - then that is the place to start looking.